# Is there a way to extract text around a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, text

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<sup>2</sup> Tecum
    optime, deinde etiam cum mediocri amico.<sup>2</sup> Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate
    quid sentit?
  </p>

  <p>
    Bonum liberi: misera orbitas. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Hoc
    sic expositum dissimile est superiori. Cave putes quicquam esse verius. Quae
    ista amicitia est?
  </p>

  <p>
    Duo Reges: constructio interrete.<sup>3,4</sup> Ita nemo beato beatior.
    Efficiens dici potest.<sup>5</sup> Consequentia exquirere, quoad sit id,
    quod volumus, effectum. Tubulo putas dicere?
  </p>

  <p>
    Haec para/doca illi, nos admirabilia dicamus. Bonum valitudo: miser morbus.
    Equidem e Cn. Respondent extrema primis, media utrisque, omnia omnibus. At
    ille pellit, qui permulcet sensum voluptate.
  </p>

  <p>
    Recte dicis; Frater et T. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? De quibus cupio
    scire quid sentias. Primum quid tu dicis breve?<sup>5</sup> 
  </p>
</div>
```

For each `sup` element, how could I retrieve the text around the element?

For the first `<sup>2</sup>`, how could I retrieve the 10 characters ("cing elit.") to the left of `<sup>2</sup>` and the 10 characters ("Tecum opti") to the right of `<sup>2</sup>`?

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('sup')].forEach(sup => {
    // for e.g. the current sup element is the first <sup>2</sup>
    // how would someone be able retrieve the text around it.
    // i.e.
    // ... adipiscing elit.<sup>2</sup> Tecum optime ...
})
```

I can't find any feasible way to achieve this. I am not even sure if this is technically possible.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: sup.nextSibling sup.previousSibling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `previousSibling` (and `nextSibling`):

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("sup"), function (elem) {
    console.log(elem.previousSibling.textContent.slice(-10));
});
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<sup>2</sup> Tecum
    optime, deinde etiam cum mediocri amico.<sup>2</sup> Idem iste, inquam, de voluptate
    quid sentit?
  </p>

  <p>
    Bonum liberi: misera orbitas. Oratio me istius philosophi non offendit; Hoc
    sic expositum dissimile est superiori. Cave putes quicquam esse verius. Quae
    ista amicitia est?
  </p>

  <p>
    Duo Reges: constructio interrete.<sup>3,4</sup> Ita nemo beato beatior.
    Efficiens dici potest.<sup>5</sup> Consequentia exquirere, quoad sit id,
    quod volumus, effectum. Tubulo putas dicere?
  </p>

  <p>
    Haec para/doca illi, nos admirabilia dicamus. Bonum valitudo: miser morbus.
    Equidem e Cn. Respondent extrema primis, media utrisque, omnia omnibus. At
    ille pellit, qui permulcet sensum voluptate.
  </p>

  <p>
    Recte dicis; Frater et T. Cur post Tarentum ad Archytam? De quibus cupio
    scire quid sentias. Primum quid tu dicis breve?<sup>5</sup> 
  </p>
</div>
```